# back to previous back still loading the data in the form

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to adjust and invoice web application, when a product has been order and the quantity is above the quantity in the database, it displays an error. I wrote a back code but is refreshing the page. I want the data inserted to remain when you click the back button.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Invoice has not been created', 'message' =>
    " <br/>".$product_alert."&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href='$previous'>Back</a>
    ;
```

Comment: *"i want the data inserted to remain when u click the back button"* - Use sessions/cookies.

Comment: @Fred-ii- please how can i do that, this my first time of using json and a php framework. i have been battling with thiis for weeks now.

Comment: This manual has a few examples on sessions http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php - Just make sure you're not outputting before header though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- please can i use alert for the echo json_encode to display on the same page. I have tried all means is still not working